# Prove that the angle is $45^\circ$

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle ABC$, $\angle B$ is a right angle. $D$ and $E$ are points on segment $AC$ such that $AD:DE:EC = 1:2:\sqrt{3}$. Then, prove that $\angle DBE = 45^\circ$.[image]

Comment: The angle in question is not $45^\circ$ in general. The additional assumption that $\Delta ABC$ is isosceles is required.

Comment: @DavidH Can you please show how it's not 45?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT2: OP is right. there are two positions which have $45 $ degree.I draw 4 pictures to show it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

one position is show on 2nd picture,which can be proved by following solution.

EDIT: here is the solution:

let $AB=BC=1,AC=\sqrt{2},AD=\dfrac{AC}{1+2+\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3+\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{3\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}}{6}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{6}$

$M$ is midpoint of $AC,AM=BM=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2},DM=BM-AD=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{6}=\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{6}$

$\dfrac{BM}{DM}=\sqrt{3} \implies \angle BDM= \dfrac{\pi}{3}$

let $N$ is on $BC$, and $EN \perp BC$

now we need to prove $\dfrac{EN}{BN}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

this is left for op.

---

EDIT 2: another position is shown on 4th picture, green triangle. unfortunately it is not a "normal" triangle and the length has $\sqrt{\sqrt{p}+q}$ style.

Comment: And if the given triangle is isoscles, then we just have to prove congruence, right?

Comment: I don't know where congruence is. My approach will be find $\angle BDE ,\angle EBC$

Comment: I wonder how we can use that to show the angle as 45.

Comment: @Yashbhatt, I put part of solution and think you can finish it.

Comment: You probably didn't realize that this question is the same as the one you previously answered. Have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587713/in-this-isosceles-right-angled-triangle-prove-that-angle-dae-45-circ?rq=1).

Comment: Ya,I just found that problem is more general.I do forget it. :)  .

Comment: That solution seems more appealing than this one.

Comment: @chenbai Nice work. Up-voted. However, I wonder can the result be arrived directly. That is, proving that the angle DBE will never be 45 degrees unless AB = BC. [A make-up example is …. After some work …. sin DBE = √2AB / (2BC), then angle DBE = 45 only when AB = BC.] P.S. This comment can be ignored.

Comment: @Mick,thanks for your comments and it reminder me there is a mistake and I just correct it. there are two solution for this question.